# Vector which corresponds to angle between subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, angle

The wikipedia article [Angles between flats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angles_between_flats) discusses the principal angles between two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It states, "if the largest angle is $π / 2$, there is at least one vector in one subspace perpendicular to the other subspace."

How can one find that vector?

Also, I'm having trouble following the definitions laid out in the article. Does anyone know of a text or other reference that covers angles between subspaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$, $W$ be two subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ which are perpendicular (i.e. there is a vector from $W$, which projection on $V$ is zero, so it is perpendicular).

Suppose $A$ is the projection matrix onto $V$. Then, every vector perpendicular to $V$ is an element of null space of $A$. Furthermore, $W$ can be described as a set of solutions of system of linear equations. To get your vector, just solve the system of equations.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm trying to find the vector corresponding to the largest angle even when the angle is not $\pi/2$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109423/find-the-unit-vector-within-a-subspace-with-the-minimum-norm-projection-onto-ano. Any ideas?

Comment: @HinrikIngolfsson I would need to think about it, but nonetheless, since it's $\mathbb R^n$, you might try multidimensional calculus (as any linear map $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable)

Comment: @HinrikIngolfsson or, given that you need to add additional constraints on the solution space, you might try Largange multipliers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: thanks. that's what I tried in the question I linked above, but I couldn't get it to work.