# Find the unit vector within a subspace with the minimum norm projection onto another subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, constraints, projection, projection-matrices

Let $W$ and $V$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with dimensions $m$ and $p$ respectively. I want to find the unit vector in $W$ whose projection onto $V$ has the minimum Euclidean norm. From geometric intuition I gather that the solution can be unique up to a sign change (such as where $W$ and $V$ are two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$), but the solutions could also reside in a a hyperplane (such as when $W$ is a plane and $V$ is a perpendicular line).

I've tried to solve this problem by solving the following constrained optimization. Let $\mathbf{w}_1,...,\mathbf{w}_m$ be a basis for $W$, let $M \in \mathbf{R}^{n x m}$ with $M = [\mathbf{w}_1 \cdots \mathbf{w}_m]$, and let $P \in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$ and be the projection matrix for $V$. The problem is to find

$argmin_\mathbf{x}$ $||P M \mathbf{x}||^2$ subject to $||M \mathbf{x}||^2 = 1$. To solve this I found the critical points of the Lagrangian.

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}, \lambda) = ||P M \mathbf{x}||^2 - \lambda (||M\mathbf{x}||^2 - 1)
\end{align*}

Which gives me

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}, \lambda) = \mathbf{x}^T M^T P^T P M  - \lambda \mathbf{x}^T M^T M  &= 0 \\
M^T P^T P M \mathbf{x} = \lambda M^T M \mathbf{x}
\end{align*}

I initially computed this derivative incorrectly. This implies that a solution is an eigenvector of $P^TP$. I'm now going to verify this.

Comment: The eigenvectors of $P$ lie either in $V$ or in $V^\perp$. Here, $W\cap V^\perp=\{0\}$, so there’s clearly a problem with your interpretation of the equations that you derived from the Lagrangian. On the other hand, extreme values of the quadratic form $\|PM\mathbf x\|^2$ on $W$ do correspond to eigenpairs of the quadratic form.

Comment: You claim that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}, \lambda)  = 0$$ implies
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}, \lambda) = (P - \lambda I) M \mathbf{x} = 0 .$$  I don't think that is correct.  It should imply $$ M^TP^TPMx = \lambda M^TM x$$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm realizing that I botched that derivative.

Comment: You’re making essentially the same error that you did before your edit. You cannot conclude from the last equation that $M\mathbf x$ is an eigenvector of $P^TP$. In fact, $P^T=P$, so $P^TP=P^2=P$ and you’re right back where you were before your update.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, and for your help in general. I don't think the conclusion that a solution $Mx$ has to be an eigenvector is mistaken, since being a stable point of the Lagrangian is a necessary condition for extrema, and $Mx$ has to be in $W$ by the construction of $M$. There's also the case $Mx=0$, but that ignores the constraint $||Mx||=1$. The problem here is concluding that $Mx$ is an eigenvector of $P^TP$. The algebra is wrong, and as you point out it's impossible. However, setting $M$ to be an orthonormal basis means the equation shows that $x$ is an eigenvector of $M^TP^TPM$.

Comment: I'll fix later and accept your answer once we clear the other thing up.

Comment: “... the equation shows that $x$ is an eigenvector of $M^TP^TPM$.” That’s exactly what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It’s a standard result that a quadratic form attains its minimal value on a unit hyperphere in the direction of the eigenvectors of the quadratic form with minimal eigenvalue. Here, the quadratic form in question is $$\|PM\mathbf x\|^2 = \mathbf x^T(M^TP^TPM)\mathbf x.$$ If we’re careful to choose $M$ such that $\|\mathbf x\|=1\implies\|M\mathbf x\|=1$, then the solutions carry over to the hyperspace $M\mathbf x$. For your example, if we take for $M$ the obvious orthonormal coordinate system of $W$, the central matrix ends up being $\operatorname{diag}\left(\frac12,1\right)$ so the minimal-length projection is obtained along $\mathbf x=\lambda(1,0)^T$, which corresponds to $(1,0,0)$ and $(-1,0,0)$ in the standard coordinate system of $\mathbb R^3$, as expected.

So, what went wrong? When you concluded that $(P-\lambda I)M\mathbf x = 0$ implies that $M\mathbf x$ must be an eigenvector of $P$, you ignored the implicit constraint $M\mathbf x\in W$. Eigenvectors of $P$ lie either in $V$ itself (eigenvalue $1$) or in $V^\perp$ (eigenvalue $0$). In your example, $V\cap W$ is nontrivial, which is why you found maximally-projecting unit vectors in $W$ that were eigenvectors of $P$, but $V^\perp\cap W = \{0\}$, so there’s no hope of finding minimally-projecting unit vectors of $W$ among the eigenvectors of $P$.

---

You’ve since updated your question with a corrected equation derived from the Lagrangian, but you’re still making essentially the same sort of error: you cannot conclude from the last equation that $M\mathbf x$ must be an eigenvector of $P^TP$. In fact, $P$ is symmetric (it’s $I$ minus a projection onto a single vector), therefore $P^TP=P^2=P$, so you’re right back where you were before the update.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't the minimal value attained at the eigenvector corresponding to the *minimal* eigenvalue?

Comment: It seems that the easiest way to do this in general is to take M to be an orthonormal basis and just constrain x to be a unit vector rather than constrain Mx. Then the standard result you refer to gives you the answer.

Comment: @HinrikIngolfsson No, it’s the _maximal_ eigenvalue for minimal value of a quadratic form on the unit hypersphere. As to your second comment, I had thought about noting something along those lines myself: choose $M$ such that $\|\mathbf x\|=1\implies\|M\mathbf x\|=1$, which is always possible.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing that. Consider a quadratic form $\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x}$. Let $\mathbf{\tilde{x}}$ be a unit eigenvector of A. Then $A\mathbf{\tilde{x}}= \lambda \mathbf{\tilde{x}} \implies \mathbf{\tilde{x}}^TA \mathbf{\tilde{x}} = \lambda$. So the minimum of $\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x}$ is the minimum eigenvalue. And in the example, the correct answer is (1,0,0), which is the eigenvector corresponding to $1/2$.

Comment: @HinrikIngolfsson You’re right: min. value of quadratic form tracks the minimum eigenvalue. Phooey. I shouldn’t do this stuff when I’m recovering from bronchitis. I had distance of a quadric from the origin in mind, which does attain its maximum at the minimum eigenvalue.

Comment: @HinrikIngolfsson What example? You’ve now mutated your original question enough that large parts of my answer make no sense in context. Such edits are considered very bad form here.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $M^T M$ is invertible (as the columns of M are linearly independent and $M^T M$ has the same rank as $M$).
So,
$$
M^T P^T P M \mathbf{x} = \lambda M^T M \mathbf{x}
$$
implies
$$
(M^T M)^{-1}M^T P^T P M \mathbf{x} = \lambda  \mathbf{x}
$$
So you can restrict yourself to the eigenvectors of $(M^T M)^{-1}M^T P^T P M$ i.e., $(M^T M)^{-1}M^T P M.$